# How do I grep for all words that are less than 4 characters?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have a dictionary with words separated by line breaks.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do:

```
egrep -x '.{1,3}' myfile
```

This will also skip blank lines, which are technically not words. Unfortunately, the above reg-ex will count apostrophes in contractions as letters as well as hyphens in hyphenated compound words. Hyphenated compound words are not a problem at such a low letter count, but I am not sure whether or not you want to count apostrophes in contractions, which are possible (e.g., I'm). You can try to use a reg-ex such as:

```
egrep -x '\w{1,3}' myfile
```

..., but this will only match upper/lower case letters and not match contractions or hyphenated compound words at all.

Comment: Actually, it's worse than that: `\w` is messed up in GNU grep because a pattern like `^\w` fails on strings like like "β-oxidation" and "γ-aminobutyric".  I would run `perl -CSD -ne 'print if /^\W*(\w\W*){1,3}$/'`, because that way it handles contractions and hyphenated words but doesn’t count the non-word characters towards it limit of 3. If you care about actual letters, you can use `\pL` and `\PL` instead of `\w` and `\W`, which match more broadly than that or even `\p{Alphabetic}`, per [UTS#18](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties)’s requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:
`grep -v "^...." my_file`

Comment: @cbmanica, no, you are incorrect. "grep -v" finds all lines that don't match, and I'm matching any line with 5 or more characters. In other words, it returns any line with 4 or fewer characters.

Comment: Given that OP wanted to find words that are "less than 4 characters", I'm afraid you've confirmed my assertion that your answer is incorrect.

Comment: yes, is less, not less or equal, anyway, is a good idea and got the point

Answer (score 2):

Try this regular expression:

```
grep -E '^.{1,3}$' your_dictionary
```