# Sublime & Regex: How to find all lines that are 3 letters or less, excluding certain lines?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a document that is 10,000 lines long.
I would like to remove all lines that are 3 letters or less, excluding any lines that start with a § symbol or excluding any lines that are all in caps.

**Example:**
Before removal:

```
§day
DOG
Happy
Monday
Now
Yes
Sunday
§new day.txt
DIY
Leg
Books
Car
Home
```

After removal:

```
§day
DOG
Happy
Monday
Sunday
§new day.txt
DIY
Books
Home
```

`DOG` & `DIY` are not affected as they are all capitals.
The lines start with `§` are also not affected.

---

**My attempts**

I know that this code can be used to make Regex ignore all lines that are in capitals and all lines that start with a `§` (In the example, the code is searching for `many or north or one`).

```
(^(?:(?:§.*|[^[:alpha:]\n\r]*[[:upper:]]+(?:[^[:alpha:]\n\r]+[[:upper:]]+)*[^[:alpha:]\n\r]*))$|(?i:\b(?:many|north|one)\s+of\b))|(?i:\bof\b)
```

I also know that [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982052/how-do-i-grep-for-all-words-that-are-less-than-4-characters) can be used to find all words that are 3 letters or less

```
'^.{1,3}$'
```

Is there any way I can combine them?

I tried replacing `many|north|one` with `'^.{1,3}$'` but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```
(?-i)^(?!§|[A-Z]+$).{1,3}$\R?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jdMwBc/1). **Details**:

- `(?-i)` - turn on case sensitivity (or, you may omit it and turn the `Aa` option on as shown in the screenshot below)
- `^` - start of a line
- `(?!§|[A-Z]+$)` - no `§` at the start and a line only made of uppercase ASCII letters are allowed
- `.{1,3}` - 1 to 3 chars
- `$` - end of a line
- `\R?` - an optional line break sequence.

SublimeText3 test:

[image]

V

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can search using this regex:

```
^(?!(?:§|[A-Z]+$)).{0,3}(?:[\r\n]+|\z)
```

and replace using empty string:

Make sure mode `m` or MULTILINE is enabled in your regex.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FvSRNn/4)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!(?:§|[A-Z]+$))`: Negative lookahead to assert a failure if line starts with `§` or contains only uppercase letters
- `.{0,3}(?:[\r\n]+|\z)`: Match any character 0 to 3 times followed by a 1 or more line breaks or end of file

#### Before:

[image]

#### After

[image]